# Refer to other object from within ngRepeat'ed custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have created a custom directive `row.htm`

Which looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="BodyController as BC">
     <row ng-repeat="ps in BC.mailto_services" />
```

Now the contents of the directive is this:

```
<div class="sp5desc">
    {{ps.description}}
</div>
```

I would like to refer to another object in `BC` from this as well. I am trying to do this:

```
<div class="sp5desc">
    {{ps.name}}{{BC.updated[ps.name] ? ' - UPDATED ' : '' }}
</div>
```

Please notice the `{{BC.updated[ps.name] ? ' - UPDATED ' : '' }}`

I am not able to figure this out, is it possible? For some reasons I have I am not able to put the `updated` property into the `ps`

Comment: `BC` should be available on your directive scope to do that.

Comment: You've listed the template of the directive, but not the Directive Definition Object (the angular.directive() bit). That would help show use the `scope` you're using.

Comment: Thanks @MattTester i forgot the code block, fixed now. :)

Comment: Thanks @atinder thats intereting ill test some more maybe i have some other error.

Comment: What version of angular are you using, the ternary operator was not supported in earlier versions of angular.

Comment: @user2341963 im using v1.4.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` creates an isolate scope, so `BC` is undefined inside each repeated element.

You can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to give it a value:

```
<row ng-repeat="ps in BC.mailto_services" ng-init="BC = BC" />
```

Comment: I should also add, that since you haven't shown the javascript code for your directive, that this still may not work. If your directive itself creates an isolate scope, then you also need to pass `BC` into the directive.